# Netbeans-Java main class

Tags: java, netbeans

Al crear un proyecto de **Java** en Netbeans, y añado un Java main class, este sale vacio... ¿Alguna idea del porqué?(Java con maven) He intentado configurar en tools y en JavaFx. Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo me ayudaria.
Debería salir algo así: [https://users.cs.fiu.edu/~downeyt/images/hw_menu_class.png](https://users.cs.fiu.edu/%7Edowneyt/images/hw_menu_class.png)
Sin embargo, aparece vacío.

RESUELTO: Pérdida de paquetes en la instalación

Comment: qué debería salir?

Comment: Qué significa: "...este sale vacio..." o "...aparece vacío"?